# NullPointerException wrong context?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-context, findviewbyid

I cant understand what is wrong?

list_item

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/no_avatar"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkbox"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abc_action_bar_overflow_padding_start_material"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textAppearance="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_list

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/listView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

FragmentList.java

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.fab);
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);


    //обработка добавления человека - нажатие на fab
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO добавление!!!
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Новая запись добавлена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    //создание курсора
try{
    SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(v.getContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("PEOPLE", new String[] {"_id", "NAME", "CHECKBOX"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(v.getContext(), R.layout.list_item, cursor, new String[]{"NAME", "CHECKBOX"}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.checkBox}, 0);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        //переход к первой записи в курсоре
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            //получение данных из курсора
            nameText = cursor.getString(1);
            isAvatar = (cursor.getInt(2)==1);
            //заполнение чекбокса, тест имени и аватар
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            checkBox.setChecked(isAvatar);
            textView.setText(nameText);
            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
            } else image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_avatar);
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException e){
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "База данных недоступна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

        //обработка нажатия по чекбоксу
//        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
//            @Override
//            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
//                checkBox.isChecked();
//            }
//        });

        return v;
}





//обработка нажатия пункте списка
public void onListItemClick(){

}

//закрытие базы данных и курсора
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

}

Why CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox) is null?
I tried many variations but became stupid ((

[debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2ln8.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for pasting the screenshot, but please also paste the actual stacktrace.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at ru.bunakov.testapplication.fragments.FragmentList.onCreateView(FragmentList.java:46)

Comment: full stacktrace has more 95000 symbols

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating fragment_list layout that does not contain checkbox, imageview or text view. That's why you are getting this error.
implement this cursor adapter

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.mylist_row, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            //получение данных из курсора
            nameText = cursor.getString(1);
            isAvatar = (cursor.getInt(2)==1);
            //заполнение чекбокса, тест имени и аватар
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            checkBox.setChecked(isAvatar);
            textView.setText(nameText);
            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
            } else image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_avatar);
        }

    }

}
```

now in onCreateview

```
MyCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(), cursor, 0);
        lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
```

Comment: what i have to do to fix it? can you support me?

Comment: See the updated answer. I have implemented cursor adapter for you.

Comment: Why implements CursorAdapter not SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: CursorAdapter  is easy to use for custom listview tha's why i suggested. You can also use BaseAdapter. Let me know if my answer helped you.

Comment: unfortunately I quite confused

Comment: read more about cursor adapter from developers site and try to do some example first.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking up `checkBox` on the view (`v`): `CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);` Yet `v` is assigned to (`fragment_list`) here `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);` BUT `fragment_list` does not contain `checkBox` and **so `v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)` returns null**.
When you use the SimpleCursorAdapter as you want to use it, then you need to create a class that extends SimpleCursorAdapter, you can then access/inflate the "row-item" layout file in `getView (final int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent)` - you will then be able to say: `CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)`.

Comment: i cant understand how make my own adapter in this case. can you write me some example lines of code?

Comment: I have spent more than 6 hours with this problem and despaired

Comment: Look at [this simple example of how to create a custom cursor-adapter](http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/11/16/creating-a-custom-cursoradapter-for-android/) - Also look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519893/any-good-example-for-checkbox-with-simplecursoradapter) - although the person wanted a different functionality, this demonstrates how to include a checkbox in the adapter - in your case I am assuming that the checkBox is checked/unchecked based on some value from your cursor

Comment: Unfortunately its not really i need

Comment: Great, good luck and shout if you get stuck. See Vikash's updated answer - he included the required implementation of a custom cursor-adapter.